# using XSLT choose when on XML element not working

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to format my Table so that there is a left padding, I would like the decision to happen inside my for statment as there are multiple rows which need the padding defined.

I have created a XML element that tells me what padding to use so all I need to do is read this, however when ever I try to read it it dosnt show anything when i open the xml in my browser.

This is a sample of my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="xmlstylesheet.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<Collection>
     <Passives>
          <Talent>Tra</Talent>
          <TCost>1</TCost>
          <Type>ANY</Type>
          <Action>Pass</Action>
     </Passives>
     <Passives>
          <Talent>Gen</Talent>
          <TCost>1</TCost>
          <Type>ANY</Type>
          <Indent>1</Indent>
          <Action>Pass</Action>
     </Passives>
     <Passives>
          <Talent>Weap</Talent>
          <TCost>12</TCost>
          <Type>ANY</Type>
          <Indent>2</Indent>
          <Action>Pass</Action>
     </Passives>
</Collection>
```

The gist of it is if there is no `<Indent></Indent>` then padding should equal 15px if there is no Indent element, if indenet=1 then padding should equal 30 and finally indent = 2 then padding should equal 45.

I am trying to define the padding inside my xslt for statment for Passives.

```
    <xsl:for-each select="Passives">
            <div style="font-family:Calibri, Arial; font-size:5pt; cursor: default;">

            <xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="Indent == '2'">
                    <xsl:variable name="newpadding">45px</xsl:variable>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="Indent == '1'">
                    <xsl:variable name="newpadding">30px</xsl:variable>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="Indent != ''">
                    <xsl:variable name="newpadding">15px</xsl:variable>
                </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose> 

        <xsl:if test="Talent != ''">
//etc
```

So as soon as I enter my for statment I would like to define newpadding so I an then apply it to my table padding later.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
   <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="Indent == '2'">
                <xsl:variable name="newpadding">45px</xsl:variable>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="Indent == '1'">
                <xsl:variable name="newpadding">30px</xsl:variable>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="Indent != ''">
                <xsl:variable name="newpadding">15px</xsl:variable>
            </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Try this:

```
  <xsl:variable name="newpadding"
                select="15 * (1 + concat(0, Indent))" />
```

You've only shown us a small portion of your XSLT, so there's no way to see if there are other issues that need fixing.